# Guaranteeing a load order in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two Rails projects, we'll call them Foo and Bar. They share the same models. The models live in Foo and Bar links to those files.

The behavior of a particular method in one of Foo's models needs to be different in Bar:

In project Foo's models/model_a.rb:

```
class ModelA
  def method_a
    puts "default behavior here"
  end
end
```

Somewhere in project Bar:

```
class ModelA
  def method_a
    puts "special behavior here"
  end
end
```

so that the following line of code:

```
x = model_a.method_a
```

would execute differently in one project than in the other without Bar having to mess with Foo's models. A similar situation would exist, presumably, if Foo's models were simply a gem, although the load-order question would be different.

My questions are: where should this code snippet live in project Bar? And how do I guarantee that Bar's mix-in is loaded last so that the correct function executes at runtime in project Bar?

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance? That's what you're describing.

If this is Active Record, then you can force the table name in the Bar app and then use the child class there.

Alternatively, but I think this is a hack. Create an initializer called override_model_a

```
require 'modelA'
class ModelA
  # then do your initializing, or include your module here
end
```

Ruby does "last one wins" so if you require the original class and then override it in the initializer it will do what you want.